# How to create an a Microsoft Word table that is synchronized to a Datasource/Database

Tags: sql, ms-word, ms-office

We find reviewing and sending data to customers in Word format the best media, we know Excel can do this but it is not that readable

The Documents are made up of sections, some data that is stored normally in a database. Word is by the best format because it can cope with free flow text,  diagrams, tables  and has in built track changes

Rather than manually cut and paste copy data from a database we want to base **some** of the word table on a Query .

Data is numeric and Ascii Text only

Ideally we want to allow user to edit text and after review Synchronize the  changes back to the datasource. We other API to the data  so understand issues  synchronizing

Even better if we could control access to edit cells i.e. they can't change ID or rows in a specific state e.g. Approved

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to "bind" Word document content directly to a database - Word simply provides no support for that. So anything you do needs to be fully handled by your code.

I suggest you look at the concept of "Content Controls" to reflect the database field content on the document surface as they can be locked for editing.

Then look at "Custom XML Parts" as the place to store the data in the document.

Content controls can be "mapped" to specific nodes in the Custom XML Part so that what's in the XML is automatically displayed in the content controls and, what the user types into a content control is automatically stored in the Custom XML Part. Both content controls and custom xml parts provide events that can be used to perform actions when something changes (synching with a database, for example).

This approach is also optimal if you want to process the data in the document without opening it in the Word application (server-side, for example). It's fairly simple to access the Custom XML Part from the Word Open XML file to read/write content.